# Keyframes en SCSS

Tags: css, sass

Tengo un mixin pero al aplicarlo a un elemento no se aplica correctamente.

Mixin SCSS

```
@mixin keyframes($property) {

    @-webkit-keyframes $property {
        @content;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes $property {
        @content;
    }

    @-o-keyframes $property {
        @content;
    }

    @keyframes $property {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Añadiendo mixin a elemento

```
li:hover > ul {

            @include keyframes(animation) {
                0% {
                    color: #f8d2c0;
                }

                100% {
                    display: inherit;
                }
            }
```

Y el resultado me lo da así

```
@-moz-keyframes $property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar [`Interpolación: #{$var}`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

#### Ejemplo:

```
@mixin keyframes($property) {

  @-webkit-keyframes #{$property} {
    @content;
  }

  @-moz-keyframes #{$property} {
    @content;
  }

  @-o-keyframes #{$property} {
    @content;
  }

  @keyframes #{$property} {
    @content;
  }
}
```